# Batch file to install multiple programs silently

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file which will install multiple programs sequentially.
I am able to install the required softwares sequentially using following code in batch file:

```
@echo off
"Path/software1.exe"
"Path/software2.exe"
"Path/software3.exe"
"Path/software4.exe"
```

OR

```
@echo off
start /wait "Path/software1.exe"
start /wait "Path/software2.exe"
start /wait "Path/software3.exe"
start /wait "Path/software4.exe"
```

But here before installing any software I want to check if it is already installed or not.

I have tried getting the list of installed softwares using following two ways:

```
wmic product get name
```

OR

```
reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall temp.txt /y
```

But then I would have to search strings which isn't feasible. Thus I would like to know if their is any command to check if a particular application is installed or not using a batch file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no formal way to check to see if an application is installed.  Installers, for the most part, just copy files, set registry keys, and add start menu shortcuts without registering anything with Windows to say, I'm installed.

A generic way to see if an application is installed is to see if it has an entry in the Add/Remove Programs applet of Control Panel.  Each entry in the ARP is found in the registry at :
`Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
(of both HKEY_CURERNT_USER and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

If it is MSI based installer, then you probably can write some code to see if the Feature ID or Component ID is installed with the [MSI API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I wouldn't know how to invoke those functions in a BAT file without compiling some helper programs.

Comment: But checking in uninstall list dosn't guarantee us that the program is not installed. For instance xampp is installed many times, but it is not shown in add/remove programs list

Comment: So the way you suggested dose not guarantee success to me.

Comment: @Gaurang - that's my point for my first statement.  It really can't be done for all programs the same way. You have to write code that looks for the common install path, registry keys, or whatever evidence to confirm the program is installed. And it will be different for each application that is installed. I suggested the ARP registry as a way that will mostly work for most programs.

Comment: @Gaurang - Also, I have never "guaranteed success" to anyone with my answers. Only you can guarantee your own success.

Answer (score 0):

you just take conditions

if not exist "C:\Program Files\software1"
"Path/software1.exe"

if not exist "C:\Program Files\software2"
"Path/software2.exe"

if not exist "C:\Program Files\software3"
"Path/software3.exe"

if not exist "C:\Program Files\software4"
"Path/software4.exe"

Answer (score -1):

This may help (which I use to help show installed software following a completed batch) is to put "appwiz.cpl" without quotations at the end of your script.

example:

```
@echo off
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
cd C:/ (assuming files are located here)
echo You are about to install software1,2,3, press ENTER to proceed...
pause
"path\software1.exe"
"path\software2.exe"
"path\software3.exe"
appwiz.cpl
```

Comment: I can't see the relation to the question. The question is about checking if a software is already installed.